# Controller get called often times, but only in Chrome on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, google-chrome

I am using AngularJS to build a web application.

I'm using `$routeProvider` to navigate through my app. Now, the app itself is too complex to describe the problem exactly. I just wanted to know if somebody has the same problem on Chrome for iOS:

1. I "`alert`" by creating my MainController.
2. On Safari, Firefox, Opera, Chrome Desktop, Safari iOS... **are only alerting once, so my Controller get created once**
3. When i open the app on Chrome for iOS, i get 10 to 20 `alerts`, so the Controller gets created many many times

My question is:

> Has anybody the same experience with their apps?

Its just a shot in the dark, but maybe there is somebdoy who already had same experiences and can give me a hint whats happening there.

EDIT: When i emulate iOS on Chrome (Desktop), the web app is also working properly. Its just Chrome for iPad and iPhone with these problems.

```
App.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when(APP_CONFIG.init_url, {
    templateUrl: "views/site.html",
    controller: "InitCtrl"
  })
  .when(APP_CONFIG.main_url, {
    templateUrl: "views/site_2.html",
    controller: "MainCtrl"
  })
  .when(APP_CONFIG.another_url, {
    templateUrl: "views/site_3.html",
    controller: "AnotherCtrl"
  })
  .when(APP_CONFIG.andanother_url, {
    templateUrl: "views/site_4.html",
    controller: "AndAnotherCtrl"
  })
  .when("/thanks", {
    templateUrl: "views/site_5.html"
  })

  .otherwise({
    templateUrl: "404.html",
    controller: "NotFoundCtrl"
  });
  });
```

Comment: Can you at least provide us with your route configuration?

Comment: Although plunker have a nice mobile view, maybe you can recreate the issue?

Comment: @superpuccio how can you say that this is a duplicate? Your link suggested a question where someone triggered the routeProvider through a simple link, and then its created two times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers:

Chrome (ONLY ON iOS) doesn't like this function:

```
 $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
  $location.hash(top_of_screen)
  $anchorScroll();
});
```

I removed the `$location.hash(top_of_screen)` and now Chrome(iOS) is working properly.